# How to connect to the Azure database for MySQL and PostgreSQL in JAVA

Tags: java, azure, azure-database-postgresql, azure-database-mysql

There're just two new Azure Services released， [Azure Database for MySQL](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/mysql/) and [PostgreSQL](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/postgresql/), As a Java developer I'm wondering how to connect to them, Shall the regular JDBC drivers still work?

Comment: Have you created an instance? Should provide you with a connection string. And yes, existing drivers should "just work."

Comment: FYI - this was initially closed as duplicate, but it's *not* a duplicate: This question is about Azure's brand new (announced an hour ago) MySQL and Postgres as-a-service offerings. Has nothing to do with the prior question that was posted.

Answer (score 6):

MySQL and Postgres as-a-service are accessed with already-existing drivers/sdk's. Just get the connection string from the portal, and then connect.

You'll see all of your connection strings in the portal, after your database instance is created:

[image: connection strings in portal]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it works except that you have to append @ to the user name portion of the connection string.

jdbc:postgresql://**servername**.postgres.database.azure.com:5432/{your_database}?user=@**servername**&password={your_password}&ssl=true